# Debugging workflows invoked using the WorkflowApplication sometimes does not break at breakpoint in Workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Has anyone experienced a problem with debugging workflows in WorkflowApplication where sometimes it does not break at the breakpoint in the Execute method? This doesn't happen all the time, but it's pretty frequent. I've tried deleting the .suo files and re-openning VS2012, but it usually does not help.

If you've experienced this, what do you usually do to get it to break at the breakpoints again?

Furthermore, is there a WorkflowApplication process that I can attach to for debugging, similar to the way I attach to the IIS process(w3wp.exe)? If so, what is the name of the WorkflowApplication process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found my problem. It was an assembly loading issue that I had within the Activity class that I was trying to debug. I was able to debug the Activity by attaching to the IIS process, but as soon as I added code into the execute method of the activity to instantiate a logging assembly, it failed to break in the execute method.

The Activity compiled fine, but when I ran the Activity using the WorkflowApplication, I had to handle the Aborted or OnUnhandledException event of the WorkflowApplication to find out that the Activity couldn't load or find the logging assembly.

Thank you all for your time in helping me troubleshoot!

Answer (score 0):

WorkflowApplication is not actual application, it is a component that hosts workflows. To execute workflow using WorkflowApplication you have to have your application (console, win service etc) that will hold WorkflowApplication and execute workflow. You can attach on that process.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my post. If I have an IIS webservice that runs the WorkflowApplication invoking a long running activity asynchronously (in a fire and forget mechanism) and the webmethod completes. Can I still attach to the IIS process to debug the long running workflow? I've tried doing this, but was unsuccessful.

Thanks!

Comment: @ptn77 What do you think when you say "long running activity"? If your workflow execution stays in process then yes you can attach to IIS process and debug. If your workflow gets saved to DB waiting for e.g. bookmark resume then you will no longer be able to attach since it is not in processing anymore.

Comment: When I say long running I mean that it is possible it gets saved to DB, but then when it resumes with bookmark, another process will be running it such as a windows service. In that case, I would have to attach to the windows service process, right? I was running into an issue where the workflow was invoked by the IIS process but couldn't get my debugger to stop at breakpoint. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to delete the bin and obj folders and rebuild all.

Comment: hmm..I think I tried deleting the bin and obj folders too when I deleted the .suo files...I'll try it again and let you know if that fixes my problem. Thanks!